# Test dragging a Leaflet map in Cypress

Tags: javascript, dom, leaflet, cypress

I have a very simple use case: I want to test data fetching when I change a leaflet map viewport, by grabbing it. However, I can't figure how to write the test.
Here is the code:

```
      cy.visit("/map");
      // wait for data
      cy.get(".leaflet-interactive.multilinestring");
      // simulate map moving
      cy.get(".leaflet-container")
        .trigger("mousedown", "center")
        .trigger("mousemove", 30, 30);
        .trigger("mouseup");
      // map should be loading
      cy.get(".leaflet-container.leaflet-loading");
```

It does not seem to move the map.

I've tried to add wait between trigger calls, because I thought there might be guards regarding event firing speeds, with no luck.

Any idea how I could test this.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It seems that instead of using `cy.trigger()`, we need to use native events to cause Leaflet to think the map is dragging.

We've written a custom Cypress command `dragMapFromCenter`, and using it looks like this:

```js
cy.get('#map-canvas').dragMapFromCenter({
  // Go 1/6 of map container width to the right (negative direction)
  xMoveFactor: -1 / 6,
  // Go 1/3 of map container height to the top (positive direction)
  yMoveFactor: 1 / 3
});

// We need to wait for something to happen after map starts moving
cy.get(".leaflet-container.leaflet-loading");
```

Here's the implementation of `dragMapFromCenter`. Put this in `cypress/support/commands.js` to be able to use it in tests.

```js
// # cy.get('#map-canvas').dragMapFromCenter({ xMoveFactor: 0.25, yMoveFactor: -0.5 })
//
// Allows dragging a Leaflet map by the given amounts. A factor of 1 means the map
// will be dragged the whole width of the map canvas in X direction and the whole
// height of the map canvas in Y direction.
Cypress.Commands.add(
  'dragMapFromCenter',
  { prevSubject: 'element' },
  (element, { xMoveFactor, yMoveFactor }) => {
    // Get the raw HTML element from jQuery wrapper
    const canvas = element.get(0);
    const rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
    const center = {
      x: rect.left + rect.width / 2,
      y: rect.top + rect.height / 2
    };

    // Start dragging from the center of the map
    cy.log('mousedown', {
      clientX: center.x,
      clientY: center.y
    });
    canvas.dispatchEvent(
      new MouseEvent('mousedown', {
        clientX: center.x,
        clientY: center.y
      })
    );

    // Let Leaflet know the mouse has started to move. The diff between
    // mousedown and mousemove event needs to be large enough so that Leaflet
    // will really think the mouse is moving and not that it was a click where
    // the mouse moved just a tiny amount.
    cy.log('mousemove', {
      clientX: center.x,
      clientY: center.y + 5
    });
    canvas.dispatchEvent(
      new MouseEvent('mousemove', {
        clientX: center.x,
        clientY: center.y + 5,
        bubbles: true
      })
    );

    // After Leaflet knows mouse is moving, we move the mouse as depicted by the options.
    cy.log('mousemove', {
      clientX: center.x + rect.width * xMoveFactor,
      clientY: center.y + rect.height * yMoveFactor
    });
    canvas.dispatchEvent(
      new MouseEvent('mousemove', {
        clientX: center.x + rect.width * xMoveFactor,
        clientY: center.y + rect.height * yMoveFactor,
        bubbles: true
      })
    );

    // Now when we "release" the mouse, Leaflet will fire a "dragend" event and
    // the search should register that the drag has stopped and run callbacks.
    cy.log('mouseup', {
      clientX: center.x + rect.width * xMoveFactor,
      clientY: center.y + rect.height * yMoveFactor
    });
    requestAnimationFrame(() => {
      canvas.dispatchEvent(
        new MouseEvent('mouseup', {
          clientX: center.x + rect.width * xMoveFactor,
          clientY: center.y + rect.height * yMoveFactor,
          bubbles: true
        })
      );
    });
  }
);
```

Comment: In my experience the amplitude of the movement seems to also have an effect. By using smaller moves, I've managed to have my test to pass without more magic. Will accept your answer until I find some robust but simpler pattern, thanks a lot.