# Test dragging a Mapbox GL map in Cypress

Tags: javascript, testing, cypress, e2e-testing, mapbox-gl-js

This question is similar to the following:

1. [Test dragging a Leaflet map in Cypress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60987787/test-dragging-a-leaflet-map-in-cypress)
2. [Cypress & Google Maps dragging moves elements, not the map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68704786/cypress-google-maps-dragging-moves-elements-not-the-map)

I want to be able to simulate a user clicking and dragging to pan a *Mapbox GL JS* map a certain distance. While it seems like the proper way, using the [cypress trigger](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/trigger) function doesn't appear to work. For the Leaflet link, a separate plugin that manipulates html canvas was used. Is there a similar workaround for panning using Mapbox?

I have created a standalone repo here that has one other test for marker actions as well: https://github.com/brianbancroft/example-mapbox-cypress-e2e

Here's the test itself:

```js
  it("drags ", () => {
    const map = cy.get("#map");
    map.should("exist");

    const canvas = cy.get(".mapboxgl-canvas");

    map
      .trigger("mouseenter", 700, 250)
      .trigger("mousedown", 700, 250, {
        bubbles: true,
        waitForAnimations: true,
        // which: 1,
        // pageX: 700,
        // pageY: 250,
      })
      // .wait(100)
      .trigger("mousemove", {
        bubbles: true,
        waitForAnimations: true,
        pageX: 550,
        pageY: 250,
        which: 1,
      })
      .wait(100)
      .trigger("mouseup", {
        bubbles: true,
        waitForAnimations: true,
        which: 1,
        pageX: 550,
        pageY: 250,
      })
      .wait(100);

});
```

What I want to see: The map panning in the cypress browser environment
What I see: The map not panning

Comment: @brianbancrift u got the answer? I'm also looking for the same.

Comment: No. Oddly, zoom scrolling through cypress works fine. The Mapbox team hasn't tried testing outside of selenium yet on the E2E side.

But, if you want a possible workaround, make the map position reflected in the url of the page, then visit the map at a certain latlong. I know it won't be the solution for all test cases, but if your workflow involves going through a dialog that appears at a certain feature at a certain latlong, it's not the end of the world to assume you don't need to test that the map can pan.